# Is there a way to schedule a task at a specific time or with an interval?

Tags: timer, task, rust, scheduler

Is there a way to run a task in rust, a thread at best, at a specific time or in an interval again and again?

So that I can run my function every 5 minutes or every day at 12 o'clock.

In Java there is the TimerTask, so I'm searching for something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Timer::periodic`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/old_io/timer/struct.Timer.html#method.periodic) to create a channel that gets sent a message at regular intervals, e.g.

```
use std::old_io::Timer;

let mut timer = Timer::new().unwrap();
let ticks = timer.periodic(Duration::minutes(5));
for _ in ticks.iter() {
    your_function();
}
```

[`Receiver::iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.iter) blocks, waiting for the next message, and those messages are 5 minutes apart, so the body of the `for` loop is run at those regular intervals. NB. this will use a whole thread for that single function, but I believe one can generalise to any fixed number of functions with different intervals by creating multiple timer channels and using [`select!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/macro.select!.html#examples) to work out which function should execute next.

I'm fairly sure that running every day at a specified time, correctly, isn't possible with the current standard library. E.g. using a simple `Timer::periodic(Duration::days(1))` won't handle the system clock changing, e.g. when the user moves timezones, or goes in/out of daylight savings.

Comment: Link to `Timer::periodic` is dead

Comment: You can also use crates like [timer](https://crates.io/crates/timer) and it's [schedule](http://yoric.github.io/timer.rs/doc/timer) function.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest Rust nightly-version:

```
use std::old_io::Timer;
use std::time::Duration;

let mut timer1 = Timer::new().unwrap();
let mut timer2 = Timer::new().unwrap();
let tick1 = timer1.periodic(Duration::seconds(1));
let tick2 = timer2.periodic(Duration::seconds(3));

loop {
    select! {
        _ = tick1.recv() => do_something1(),
        _ = tick2.recv() => do_something2()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation about the differences of this method compared to dbaupps ? What I can see is that you're spawning two tasks and I'm assuming they're running independently ?